# Find the maximum value of a MySQL group by and assign it to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

I have a MySQL table called "cylinders".  Two of the columns are `pid` and `reportno`.

```
pid       |  reportno
13-2021   |     1
14-2025   |     1
13-2021   |     2
13-2021   |     3
15-2034   |     1
14-2025   |     2
```

I want to find the highest `reportno` for a group so that I can add to the table using the next `reportno`.

I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cylinders GROUP BY pid ORDER BY reportno DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$lastrpt = $row["reportno"];
$nextrpt = $lastprt + 1;
```

But `$lastrpt` variable has value 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the highest reportno? Why group needed?

Comment: What is your expected result out of the same data ?

Comment: Note that for MyISAM tables, you can define both columns as components of a compound, auto_incrementing PK. Then MySQL will do the rest for you.

Comment: Right, not clear in the question.  I need the highest report no for a pid.  So I want a query that returns a single row with the pid and max reportno for a specific pid.    For example, from the table above, I want to find the max reportno for pid=13-2021.  The actual table is about 20,000 rows.  PS thanks for the answers so far, I'm embarrassed to admit how long I've been trying to figure this out.

Comment: `SELECT pid, MAX(reportno) AS max_reportno FROM cylinders WHERE pid='13-2021'`

Comment: Tomaso, I tried that.  Unfortunately it still returns 0.'$query = "SELECT pid, MAX(reportno) AS max_reportno FROM cylinders WHERE pid='13-2021'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$lastrpt = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nextrpt = $lastprt+1;'

Comment: $lastrpt is an array, so you can't just add 1 to it. It should be `$nextrpt = $lastprt['max_reportno'] + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query will work because you have to add reportno to the group by clause or use it in aggregation. Try the following.

```
SELECT pid, MAX(ReportNo) FROM cylinders GROUP BY pid ORDER BY reportno DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: OK thanks!  How do I retrieve to reportno for a specific pid from the resulting 2 column array?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(REPORTNO) FROM CYLINDERS;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without the `GROUP BY` as you need the highest `reportno` -

```
SELECT * FROM cylinders ORDER BY reportno DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Update**

```
SELECT pid, MAX(reportno) max_reportno FROM cylinders GROUP BY pid ORDER BY max_reportno DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the highest cylinder for only one specific pid, say 13-2021.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row and look up the highest reportno in one query:

```
INSERT INTO cylinders (pid, reportno)
SELECT '13-2021', MAX(reportno) + 1 FROM cylinders
WHERE pid='13-2021';
```

You shouldn't use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_query` instead.

Edit: changed based on comment